# Securely validate php form field for 5-digit numeric value

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I have a functioning form page where a user can update their zip code based on their username, which is saved as a session variable.

Everything works except for this new feature to validate the zip code. I have the html5 pattern in place so that if they enter 4 digits, it prompts them to follow the 5 digit format. However, I"m required to validate securely on the server side as well.

I've opted to do a regular expression to match for 5 digits between 0 and 9, and I've nested this in an if statement which is being used to preform the SQL queries. THe issue is that If I enter 123 for the zip code, it still successfully submits.

Obviously, I need this to only submit if it's 5 digits, otherwise print the error message. I'm wondering if it's something in my structure or syntax.

Here's the code, thanks for any help:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['missingZipUser'])) {

if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/", $_POST['zip'])) {
echo "The ZIP code must be a 5-digit number.";
}else{

  //Query for updating main table first
  $sql = " UPDATE " . table. "
      SET zip= ?
      WHERE uname ?";
  $stmt = odbc_prepare($connect, $sql);
  $success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($_POST['zip'],
  $_SESSION['missingZipUser']));

  //Query for updating both fields in secondary table
  $sql2 = " UPDATE " . table. "
      SET zip1= ?, zip2= ?
      WHERE uname= ?";
  $stmt2 = odbc_prepare($connect, $sql2);
  $success2 = odbc_execute($stmt2, array($_POST['zip'], $_POST['zip'],
  $_SESSION['missingZipUser']));
}
}
```

**UPDATE**
Contrary to some of the comments below, the update code is still passing the info as successful.

Comment: You're echoing an error message but then inserting into the database anyway. You probably want an `else`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Can't believe I missed that. I added it but if I type 123 it still updates the database and gives my success message anyway

Comment: Your logic is also backwards. Should be `if (!preg_match...`.

Comment: Your updated code appears to work fine in my testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix your condition and you are good to go:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['missingZipUser']) && isset($_POST['zip'])) {
    if (is_string($_POST['zip']) && 1 === preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/", $_POST['zip'])) {
        // update record in database
    } else {
        echo "The ZIP code must be a 5-digit number.";
    }
}
```

You can also simplify your regular expression:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['missingZipUser']) && isset($_POST['zip'])) {
    if (is_string($_POST['zip']) && 1 === preg_match("/^\d{5}$/", $_POST['zip'])) {
        // update record in database
    } else {
       echo "The ZIP code must be a 5-digit number.";
    }
}
```

**Note** As pointed out, both your original as the simplified regular expression only verify whether the string is a 5-digit number. Not all 5-digit numbers are valid ZIP codes.

Comment: It could be an array.

Comment: @PaulCrovella That's the point of server-side validation. Think of https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to check a string if all the characters are numerical and [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check if the length is 5 characters. As [@smarx pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315397/securely-validate-php-form-field-for-5-digit-numeric-value/45315476#comment77593276_45315397), you should probably refrain from inserting anything into the database if the `$_POST['zip']` isn't a zip code. Also, you should check if the `$_POST['zip']` is even set before working with it.

Below is an example using the methods described above,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['missingZipUser'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['zip'])) {
    if (ctype_digit($_POST['zip']) && strlen($_POST['zip']) === 5) {
      //Query for updating main table first
      $sql = " UPDATE " . table. "
          SET zip= ?
          WHERE uname ?";
      $stmt = odbc_prepare($connect, $sql);
      $success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($_POST['zip'],
      $_SESSION['missingZipUser']));

      //Query for updating both fields in secondary table
      $sql2 = " UPDATE " . table. "
          SET zip1= ?, zip2= ?
          WHERE uname= ?";
      $stmt2 = odbc_prepare($connect, $sql2);
      $success2 = odbc_execute($stmt2, array($_POST['zip'], $_POST['zip'],
      $_SESSION['missingZipUser']));
    } else {
        echo "The ZIP code must be a 5-digit number.";
    }
  }
}
```

Now, a way to test if you have a valid zip code is to use a zip code lookup service. A free one is called [Zippopotam](http://zippopotam.us/) and below is an example of its use,

[Run it here](http://code.runnable.com/WXf8aISS0mYm8vtg/valid-zipcode-test-with-zippopotam-)

```
function valid_zip($zip_code) {
    $data = file_get_contents("https://api.zippopotam.us/us/$zip_code");
    $data_decoded = json_decode($data);
    return (property_exists($data_decoded, 'post code')) ? true : false;
}

var_dump('60007 is ',valid_zip(60007));
var_dump('6000 is ',valid_zip(6000));
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful alternative to the regular expression that was giving me problems. This is also more thorough in checking the POST is set. I'm not a typically a PHP programmer so when I run into issues I get stuck pretty quick. This solution worked for me immediately.

Comment: This is actually wrong and shouldn't be the accepted answer, see example: https://3v4l.org/8jShF.

Comment: @Tom See the comments!

Comment: I'm using a value in the example that is clearly wrong to demonstrate that your answer is wrong.